# How to stream instagram story downloader link?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-player, video-reactjs

I have used a package to fetch the downloaded link of the instagram story and it is working perfectly. The link im getting its following

```
https://instagram.fuio21-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t72.14836-16/327485371_686507603228648_5268253735316840836_n.mp4?efg=eyJ2ZW5jb2RlX3RhZyI6InZ0c192b2RfdXJsZ2VuLjEwODAuc3RvcnkuaGlnaCIsInFlX2dyb3VwcyI6IltcImlnX3dlYl9kZWxpdmVyeV92dHNfb3RmXCJdIn0&_nc_ht=instagram.fuio21-1.fna.fbcdn.net&_nc_cat=1&_nc_ohc=kEyAKea8ExQAX-LrCdG&edm=ANmP7GQBAAAA&vs=760775594938459_1855122073&_nc_vs=HBksFQAYJEdMc0hoUlBvZDlNQllIQUNBSVJoTHlEY21CeEpidlE1QUFBRhUAAsgBABUAGCRHQVNSUUFQd0QxaXdVTndYQVBzQWRTdksxYzFXYnBSMUFBQUYVAgLIAQAoABgAGwGIB3VzZV9vaWwBMRUAACb%2Bt8zXs9fsPxUCKAJDMywXQCJU%2FfO2RaIYEmRhc2hfaGlnaF8xMDgwcF92MREAdegHAA%3D%3D&ccb=7-5&oh=00_AfBa6yvUiJGnzbh1Us18vIlRvXWy1YOVOnhVADSy_Y6l6g&oe=63DC48A5&_nc_sid=276363
```

if you open this link in broswer the video will be run but when im using it in a tag like video or any React Package its not working,
If you can help i will be very thankful

Answer (score 0):

Like many sites, Instagram uses [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS), which prevents external sites from accessing it. CORS only applies in the browser, so you can get around this by downloading the file on your server and serving it from that.

Comment: but videos from posts are running successfully

Comment: its not possible like if user searching 100 user  stories it means more than 100 vdeos are going to database for nothing